# How to compare all array elements in if statement in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to check if first char of login is a letter. I have an array with all letters and I've tried to compared all elements in one statement.

```
inputHandler {
this.setState(
{login: event.target.value},
() => {
    for( var ch in chars2 ) {
        if(this.state.login[0] === chars2[ch]) {                            
        this.setState({message: 'Works'})
        } }
    } )
}
```

If I compare it with e.g. chars2[3] it works. I also tried other loops but it doesn't work. There is any way to do it?

Comment: do you need to find first occurrence in loop that fulfills condition or you need to find all occurrences that fulfill condition?

Comment: try `if(chars2.includes(this.state.login[0])`

Comment: Thanks a lot Taki. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.includes()` to find a character inside a string. Since you have `event.target.value`, you don't need to wait for setState, you can assign the message property immediately.

```
const login = event.target.value;

this.setState({
    login,
    ...(chars2.includes(login[0]) && { message: 'Works' })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Computers can already determine what a letter is; use regular expressions for this :)

```
if (/^[a-z]/i.test(this.state.login)) {
    //...
}
```

The `/` delimiters means "this is a regular expression", the `^` means "match the start of the string", `[a-z]` means "match any letter from a to z", the trailing `i` means "match case-**i**nsensitive" (don't care about upper or lower case), and the `.test` method of a regular expression returns true if the pattern is found in the given string. So this is saying "return true if the start of the string begins with any letter" :)